# XMPP How can I get the notification or an event when current user get offline?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I have implemented chatting application using `XMPP` iOS Framework with OpenFire server.

I just want get notification or an event when current user disconnect with XMPP.

I implement delegate `XMPPReconnectDelegate` & method

```
- (void)xmppReconnect:(XMPPReconnect *)sender didDetectAccidentalDisconnect:(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags)connectionFlags
```

But problem is, It is not called in iOS 7.1 & it is working in iOS 8.

Is there any other method or delegate ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Following method too will call when user disconnect from XMPP Server.

- (void)xmppStreamDidDisconnect:(XMPPStream *)sender withError:(NSError *)error
  {

}

Answer (score 0):

XMPP had it's delegate methods and you can easily check if user goes to offline.

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidDisconnect:(XMPPStream *)sender withError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (!isXmppConnected)
    {
        NSLog(@"disconnect from XMPP");
    }

}
```